# NLP for entity comparison in a sentence

Tags: nlp, dataset

I am looking for something that can identify which entity of a sentence is better in comparison or the elements of comparison.
like if I have a sentence **"A is better than better than B"** I should be idintifying which element is better using NLP.
the dataset I have consists of
sentence, entity1, entity2, the element of comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try two approaches:

1- rule based(with regex you can specify exactly what pattern is desired and extract what you want)

2-machine learning(you give the training data and their lables to computer and computer extracts rules)

for more information you can use this refrences:

https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp